# non-linear optimization using solnp

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have table1:

[image: table 1]

that has:

> p_code, v1, v2, v3sum, vmax fields

table1 v2 field is the aggregation of v2 values from table2 by p_code:

[image: table 2]

I want the machine to solve the problem:
`maximize v3sum3 = v1+v2`

where:

- v3sum > vmax
- v3sum < 3*vmax

my script is here:

```
p_code<-1:12
v1<-sample(12)
v2<-0
v3sum<-0
vmax<-0

table1<-data.frame(p_code,v1,v2=0,v3sum,vmax)

table1$v3sum<-table1$v1+table1$v2

table1$vmax<-300

v2<-rep(2:7,50)
table2<-data.frame(p_codex=0,p_code=0,v2)

fn<-function(x){
    for(i in 1:nrow(table2)){
        table2$p_code[i]<-round(x[i])
    }
    print(table2$p_code)
    table2a<-aggregate(table2$v2,list(table2$p_code),sum)
    names(table2a)<-c("p_code","v2")
    table2_1<-merge(table2a,table1,all.y=TRUE)
    table2_1$v3sum<-table2_1$v1+table2_1$v2
    # View(table2_1)
    return(sum(table2_1$v3sum))
}

fnOgr<-function(x){
    table2$p_codex<-x
    for(i in 1:nrow(table2)){
        table2$p_code[i]<-round(x[i])
    }
    print(table2$p_code)
    table2a<-aggregate(table2$v2,list(table2$p_code),sum)
    names(table2a)<-c("p_code","v2")
    table2_1<-merge(table2a,table1,all.y=TRUE)
    table2_1$v3sum<-table2_1$v1+table2_1$v2
    # View(table2_1)
    return(table2_1$v3sum)
}

constraintsLower<-table1$vmax
constraintsUpper<-table1$vmax*3

x0<-c(1:nrow(table2))

LB_p<-c(rep(0,nrow(table2)))
UB_p<-c(rep(12,nrow(table2)))
sol1<-solnp(x0, fun = fn, ineqfun = fnOgr, ineqLB = constraintsLower, ineqUB=constraintsUpper, LB=LB_p, UB=UB_p)
```

but apparently `x0` does not change. and the problem stays not solved. Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: "problem not solved" is not descriptive,could you please edit the post with output of `solnp`

Comment: solnp-->The linearized problem has no feasible
solnp-->solution.  The problem may not be feasible.

Iter: 1 fn: 78.0000  Pars:  0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0             
solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.

Comment: it does not seem that solver has tried to change x values

Comment: Look at `fn(x0); fn(rep(0, 300)); fn(sample(10000, 300))`. Your function always returns `78`. Solver doesn't change x values because output is the constant value.

Comment: Exactly, but it's not correct. I need that x should be changeable

Comment: if you look at     table2_1<-merge(table2a,table1,all.y=TRUE)
    table2_1$v3sum<-table2_1$v1+table2_1$v2. i am merging tables and then I return the sum of the output of merge operation

Comment: please help! it's already the 3d day i am waisting to figure out what's wrong